# Bootstrap TreeGrid jquery plugin in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have based myself on this site: http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/ but I can't get the treegrid to work. I have also tried copying all HTML, CSS and JS to JSFiddle and try it out a bit, but still no progress. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

HTML table:

```
    <table class="tree">
    <tr class="treegrid-1 treegrid-collapsed">
        <td>
            <span class="treegrid-expander treegrid-expander-collapsed"></span>
            Test Parent
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-2 treegrid-parent-1">
        <td>
            Test Child
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Bundles:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js",
                       "~/Scripts/TreeGrid/jquery.treegrid.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/jquery.treegrid.css"));
```

The script and css files necessary for this can be found on the URL I gave you before (http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/).

Fiddle I've been playing around with: http://jsfiddle.net/up8c6u85/ . 
At the moment this is basically the same as the code above.

Comment: You need to initiate the plugin right??